# How to trim Column Value SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

**Table1:**

| Intime |
| --- |
| 17:44:58.2555247 |

How to Trim '2555247'from Intime value Looking for output "17:44:58"
Could someone help on this. Thank you...

Comment: @JonasMetzler, Intime datatype is Time(7)

Comment: @JonasMetzler, I'm using Mysql DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simply convert the input to a "normal" time:

```
SELECT CONVERT(intime, TIME) AS intime 
FROM yourtable;
```

If we don't want to select only, but to execute an update, this will do:

```
UPDATE yourtable 
SET intime = CONVERT(intime, TIME);
```

If we want to alter the table and change the column to a "normal" time, whis will do:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable MODIFY intime TIME;
```

If we then do inserts like this...

```
INSERT INTO yourtable VALUES ('17:44:58.2555247');
```

...and select from the table, the output will be 17:44:58

Comment: Could you help me how can we trim also. Thank you...

Comment: I have column value("Present") I want to display value("P") from ("Present") How can we trim. Thank you...

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question here how to "trim" times. Please don't ask multiple questions at once. Accept this answer because it solves your question and create a new question for your new topic.