# How can we use trim and len function to format time value

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime-format

**Table1:**

| Name | Intime |
| --- | --- |
| Paulsmith | 15:10:45.0486392 |

I know we can use the `trim` and `len` functions to remove the last characters from column `Name` (remove 'smith') to show output as only 'Paul`.

How can we do the same for time in column `Intime`?

#### I tried

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('15:10:45.0486392',1,len('15:10:45.0486392')-8) AS Intime 
FROM stuattrecordAM
```

The output I got is `"15:10:45"` as expected.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('Intime',1,len('Intime')-8) AS Intime 
FROM stuattrecordAM
```

#### Issue

When I try to use `Intime` column name instead the string it's showing the following error:

> Argument data type time is invalid for argument 1 of substring function.

See also my previous, related question: [How to trim Column Value SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74793425/how-to-trim-column-value-sql)

How can I format the value so that result contains only first 8 characters displaying hours:minutes:seconds?

Comment: In programming, nobody is meant to remember everything. That's why there's DOCUMENTATION and RESOURCES on the internet, which you are ALLOWED to search/read. So, GOOGLE before asking. Do some research, some reading. If, and only IF you can't seem to find any resource, ask here.

Comment: @ahmed, "SELECT SUBSTRING('Pualsmith',1,len('Pualsmith')-5) AS Name FROM stuattrecordAM". In this code I will get output 'Paul' but, how can we remove time values(15:10:45.0486392). Here I want output "15:10:45". Can we remove using trim ("0486392")

Comment: It would be better to edit your question according to that and show your real case, and also clarify the datatype of this time column and what DBMS you are using.

Comment: You need to show all possible cases and all required results for those cases by editing your table in the question adding one row per possible case and adding a second table showing the outcome for each of this row and case. If you don't put sufficient effort in asking a question here, the question will likely be closed.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: It's a extremely bad idea to run string functions on dates or times. If the column can only contain times, its column type should be time, too. Then we wil use time functions, not string functions. A column which can both contain times and strings, is very bad database design. Then better split these columns instead of running string functions on times. I already told you in your last question, you should please tag your DBMS which is MYSQL. Why do you refuse to do this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74793425/how-to-trim-column-value-sql/74793802#74793802

Comment: @ahmed, I'm using sql server

Comment: For [tag:sql-server] please use the `CONVERT` function as explained in [sql server - SQL Argument data type datetime is invalid for argument 1 of substring function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31809046/sql-argument-data-type-datetime-is-invalid-for-argument-1-of-substring-function)

Comment: Are you sure you changed your working DBMS from MYSQL to SQL Server since your last question you asked this morning? If yes, please tag it.

Comment: In SQL Server you could cast this time column as TIME(0) to get the required format without the need of using string functions [check this](https://dbfiddle.uk/wpSBmu-k)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `hh:mm:ss` portion of from a properly formatted *time* you can use the [convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) function, for example

```
declare @t varchar(16) = '15:10:45.0486392';
select Convert(char(8), @t, 114);
```

Result: `15:10:45`

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `TRIM` and `LEN`, you can use a simpler function like `REPLACE`.

```
SELECT Value = REPLACE (Value, '''', '');
```

Do let me know if you still want to use `TRIM` and `LEN`.

Comment: Does this *"format the value so that result contains only first 8 characters displaying hours:minutes:seconds"*? I don't see it yet myself.